# Testing Library render is not working. Can it be related to the dependency problem?

Tags: npm, render, react-testing-library

I'm building a React app and trying to add test code using Jest and Testing library.
My app works just fine on live server.
But Whenever I try to run test code, 'render' throws an error : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'current')

```
render(<Mycomponent />;
```

I somehow found it can be caused by mismatched dependency problem and tried `npm install --force` and `--legacy-peer-deps` but nothing seems to work.

[image]

Here's my package.json. Would there be any approach that I can take?

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "connected-react-router": "^6.8.0",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-icons": "^4.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

looks like you have dependencies that still rely on React v17

Comment: Thanks. TBH, I'm not used to managing package. Would it be possible for you to give me some advice on this? How can I change my dependencies to rely on React. v18? Or should I downgrade to React v17?

Comment: I solved the problem! Installed npm-check-updates package.